# Writing Euler's equation for this minimization problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, projection, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $A$ be a symetric and definite positive matrix of size $n \times n$. Let $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{P}( \{1, \dots, n\})$ a set of indices and consider the projection operator $P_{\Sigma} : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by

$$\left[P_\Sigma (U) \right]_{i}= U_i \text{ if } i \in \Sigma \ \text{ and } \ 0 \text{ if } i \notin\Sigma.$$

(i.e all the components of $U$ outside of $\Sigma$ are put to zero). For simplification we will use the notation $U_\Sigma:= P_\Sigma(U)$.

I want to study the following minimization problem :

\begin{equation}
\underset{U \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\min} \langle A(U-U_\Sigma) | U_\Sigma\rangle - \langle B_\Sigma | U_\Sigma\rangle
\end{equation}
where $\langle.|.\rangle$ is the usual scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

More precisely, I would like to find the Euler equation associated to this problem, but I'm not sure how to deal with the projection operator..

Any help or advices are welcomed !

Comment: Using the fact that $P_\Sigma^2=P_\Sigma$, and that $P_\Sigma^T=P_\Sigma$, you can rewrite the minimisation problem as $$\min \langle (P_\Sigma A (I-P_\Sigma) - P_\Sigma B) U|U\rangle, $$ which is a standard quadratic problem (quadratic program? I don't know if I can call it this way). P.S.: I think that the French "composantes" is "components" in English :-)

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe Negro for your help. So I guess the solution $U$ would verify  : $$P_\Sigma(AU-P_\Sigma(U)) - P_\Sigma(B) = 0$$

Comment: I think the last term should be $-P_\Sigma B U$. And the right-hand side needs not vanish, you should replace it with $\lambda U$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, with second thoughts, i'm not sure this problem is actually well-posed since i'm not sure the functional $$U \mapsto \langle P_\Sigma(A(U-U_\Sigma)) - P_\Sigma B | U \rangle$$ is coercitive as needed.